# Apache Prefork Configuration

Tags: php, apache-2.2, linux, vps

I'm newbie on VPS configuration. So, I've installed apache, php and mysql and now I need to know how to configure Prefork to optimize Apache.

```
The system configuration  is:
CPU Cores 2 x 2 Ghz @ 4 Ghz
RAM Memory 2304 MB DDR3
Burst Memory 3 GB DDR3
Disk Space 30 GB SSD
Bandwidth 3 TB
SwitchPort 1 Gbps
```

Actually, after linux, mysql, apache and php, there are 250 MB memory in use.

Well, I don't have idea to calculate. I saw in some websistes, some vars like:

```
KeepAlive On
KeepAliveTimeout 1
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
StartServers 15
MinSpareServers 15
MaxSpareServers 15
MaxClients 20
MaxRequestsPerChild 0
```

or

```
StartServers 2
MaxClients 150
MinSpareThreads 25
MaxSpareThreads 75
ThreadsPerChild 25
MaxRequestsPerChild 0
```

How I could to do: Prefork or worker? Where and how the vars are placed? In httpd.conf?

Comment: I would suggest NGINX instead http://www.endyourif.com/its-lemp-not-lamp/ as this is NGINX's goal!

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be decided just by the specs of the hardware. There are many things that are important, especially what you are about to serve.

For Example:

A website that uses mod_php should use prefork as PHP might not be threadsafe. If you use fcgi you can use worker. Do you use a lot of AJAX for push notification on the website? Then you might set a very high MaxClient value. But you need to set it lower than `Size Per Apache process * Clients` what would be about 22MB Per Process. On the other hand you might not need such a high MaxClient if you serve a lot of static content. And the Spares as well. How much are you willing to have available "hot".

The question for Performance cannot be answered like this. More it's a constant testing and learning. Tightening screws and oiling up everything.

You should analyze your performance with a benchmarking tool like [Apache Bench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html). Try different combinations and test them. That's how you get your configuration.